# How to change theme in eclipse (whole theme, not font!)

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, themes

I am using eclipse for studying, and I was thinking about changing the design of eclipse itself.

I found various of themes, which did only Change the Color of the different types of code, but not for example the Icons or the General UI.

Does anyone have links or advices for changing the whole look & feel?

Comment: [https://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines](https://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines)

Comment: If you are just doing this for studying then developing an Eclipse 4 (e4) style RCP with Eclipse gives you far more styling options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using latest eclipse (since 4.4), there is a dark theme included :

```
Window > preferences > General > Appearance > select dark theme
```

You can also check additional plugin for olders versions like https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme

But everything here is for dark theme, and you can't change icons

Comment: I have now installed a theme for light design, but the selected line is always black (tried several themes) is that an error?

Comment: you can tweak that in preferences, under `General > editors > Text Editors`, but you can also have different editor style depending on your plugin (java, python...), so parse preferences menu, there will be editors submenu to change that